# csv out put and db changes

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I have a requirement that I need to output some more formation columns in the CSV whose data are collected from mysql (very large tables). These columns are new and I am wondering if I should create a new table and call Inner Join to get the work done or Concatenate into one of the ready made tables for the new data definition. I prefer to add new tables to avoid possible bad issues.

I am bad at DB design I am afraid what I like may turn out dangerous and hard to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy your table and test in that temporary table to avoid possible bad issues.

```
CREATE TABLE `new_table_name` LIKE `old_table_name`
```

After it add new fields to new table and import data. If you see that everything is ok you can do same with live table.